# A question on similar triangles......

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the given figure, AB, EF and CD are parallel lines. Given that EG = 5 cm, GC = 10 cm and DC = 18 cm, then EF = ?? [image]

Answer (score 4):

Two triangles $GEF, GCD$ are similar.

Hence, you'll have
$$EG : CG=EF : CD.$$

Comment: So the answer is 9 right....?? EF = 5/10 * 18 cm = 9 cm

Comment: Yes, you are right.